# Problem on uploading shinyapps from rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, shinyapps

I use Rstudio 1.2.1335 and it starts to give a message when I trying to publish to server a Shinyapps:

"Please update to the latest available on CRAN."

Has anyone had this king of problem?
What do I need to update?

I have already updated the version of Rstudio to 1.2.1335

"Please update to the latest available on CRAN."

Comment: Have you try downloading the ``shiny`` package again?

Comment: i used update.packages(ask = FALSE) and it worked.  tks

Comment: Consider posting your comment as an answer - it helped me!

Answer (score 1):

I updated RStudio (Help -> Check for Updates... on Mac). Then, when I clicked the publish button, I got a message to update rsconnect. I said yes. But then when I clicked publish again it gave me the same message to update rsconnect.

Finally, I restarted Rstudio and I was able to publish.

Answer (score 0):

I used the "Check for Packages Updates..." option in the "Tools" tab to update all the packages I was using. This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Updating `rsconnect` worked for me.

```
install.packages("rsconnect")
```